# Swift Array holding elements weakly

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, memory, weak-references

I am taking some inspiration from

https://marcosantadev.com/swift-arrays-holding-elements-weak-references/

and I want to be able to maintain an array holding weak references to its elements, so that in case those elements get released elsewhere in my code base, I don't retain them in my array.

I would like the implementation to be as type safe as possible, however should be reusable.

The strategy that I am using is declaring a Weak Reference container as so.

```
class WeakRefContainer<T> where T: AnyObject {
    private(set) weak var value: T?

    init(value: T?) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Then I want to maintain an array of these WeakRefContainers, so I create an array extension:

```
extension Array where Element: WeakRefContainer<AnyObject> {
    func compact() -> [WeakRefContainer<AnyObject>] {
        return filter { $0.value != nil }
    }
}
```

When calling the compact method, I am now able to clear up the array in case stuff needs to be cleaned up.

I am now having some compilation issues which am having trouble understanding.
Lets suppose I have a sample class

```
class SampleClass {
}
```

And I try to use everything as follows:

```
var weakReferencesArray = [WeakRefContainer<SampleClass>]()
let obj1 = WeakRefContainer.init(value: SampleClass())
let obj2 = WeakRefContainer.init(value: SampleClass())
weakReferencesArray.append(obj1)
weakReferencesArray.append(obj2)

weakReferencesArray.compact()
```

When I try to call compact I get the following error message:

```
MyPlayground.playground:29:21: 'WeakRefContainer<SampleClass>' is not a subtype of 'WeakRefContainer<AnyObject>'
```

Can anyone unblock me please? Thanks

Comment: You should make your `WeakRefContainer` a struct.

Comment: I would avoid using the method name `compact()` on `Array`, as that's likely what the identity mapping version of `compactMap` will be named if it's ever added to the stdlib.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because `WeakRefContainer<SampleClass>` is not a subclass of `WeakRefContainer<AnyObject>` because generics are invariant in Swift. Thus  `weakReferencesArray` can't use the `compact` method added from the extension.

There is a workaround for this, via a protocol:

```
protocol WeakHolder {
    var hasRef: Bool { get }
}

extension WeakRefContainer: WeakHolder {
    var hasRef: Bool { return value != nil }
}

extension Array where Element: WeakHolder {

    func compacted() -> [Element] {
        return filter { $0.hasRef }
    }

    mutating func compact() {
        self = compacted()
    }
}
```

I also renamed `compact` to `compacted`, for better Swift semantics, and replaced the original `compact` by a mutating version.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the extension to apply to all `[WeakRefContainer<T>]` where `T` can be any type extending `AnyObject`.

```
extension Array where Element: WeakRefContainer<T> {
```

However, currently, parameterised extensions are not possible. See [this proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#parameterized-extensions).

You can kind of work around this by making `compact` generic:

```
extension Array{
    func compact<T>() -> [Element] where Element == WeakRefContainer<T> {
        return filter { $0.value != nil }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another option is `extension Array { func compact<T>() -> [Element] where Element == WeakRefContainer<T> {` :)

Comment: @Hamish Oh I didn't know you could constrain `Element` like _that_! Thanks!